# i18n language switcher don't show on default lang

Tags: 7, blocks, i18n-l10n

I'm using Drupal 7 and Clean theme. And my site have 3 languages. Using i18n module for this features. Everything is working...

Language Switcher block is active, showing on 2 languages. But, when click my site default language, don't show this block.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option under language switcher block configuration.You have to select all the language checkbox to display language switcher block in all languages.

[image]

Comment: Still not working with that solution!
thanks anyway

Comment: If it wasn't working, why did you accept the answer?